# How to maintain a dynamic scroll in bottom only if the user moves it to bottom?

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, scrollbar

I have a scrollview which has content that is being refreshed (increasing its size) by a ajax query.

I want that (like commonly in all the ides) when the user has the scroll on the bottom, the scroll must be maintained in the bottom even when adding more text.

I tried to find when the scroll is in the bottom with this code:

```
var scrollDiv = $('#modalText');
var height = scrollDiv[0].scrollHeight;
if (scrollDiv[0].scrollTop==height){
 //scroll is in the bottom, must force the scroll to bottom
}else{
 //scroll is not in the bottom, must maintain the scroll point
}
```

The problem is that scrollDiv[0].scrollTop is not equal to scrollDiv[0].scrollHeight when the user has the scroll in the bottom. I can't understand why, but it's about 900 pixels less!

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the `height` to `scrollTop` to get `scrollBottom`

```js
var scrollDiv = $('#modalText');

function add() {
  var height = scrollDiv[0].scrollHeight;
  var scroll = scrollDiv[0].scrollTop + scrollDiv[0].offsetHeight;

  scrollDiv.append('<p>' + Number(new Date()) + '</p>');

  if (scroll == height) {
    //scroll is in the bottom, must force the scroll to bottom
    scrollDiv.scrollTop(height);
  } else {
    //scroll is not in the bottom, must maintain the scroll point
  }
};
```

```css
#modalText {
  max-height: 180px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="add()">Add</button>
<div id="modalText"></div>
```

Comment: your answer seems to be a nice way, but does not work in my case. heigh is 52058 and scroll is 52048.5, so they don't be the same. Do you figure out why?

Comment: that may be because of `padding` if you have padding top and bottom, then `scroll =  scrollDiv[0].scrollTop + scrollDiv[0].offsetHeight;`

Answer (score 0):

The difference of 900 you are facing is because because of the viewport/client height. If you add that to the calculations you'll see that find that `scrollHeight == scrollTop + clientHeight`. You may review this at Mozilla Foundation's documentation of [scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight).